# Excel get previous value of the cell after sorting of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How do I get the previous cell value in an Excel sheet?

For example, if I have data in the below order :

```
A1000 - StackOverflow
A1001 - Some other flow
A2000 - StackOverflow
```

And then I sort to get something like this:

```
A1000 - StackOverflow
A2000 - StackOverflow
```

So the cells with the value "StackOverflow" will be one below the other.

I want to find the value of the cell that is above A2000 after sorting ? I tried `INDIRECT("A"&Row()-1)`, but it returns A1999 where I want A1000.

Comment: I assume someone has down voted this question because it is so unclear.  However.  ROW() returns the current row number.  If you move the row containing ROW(), the value returned will change.  If you want to maintain a link between rows after they have been sorted, you must base that link on something that does not change.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't simply put the value into a VBA variable before sorting, then you could put a defined name on the cell value you want to keep referencing to. The defined name will remain in the same cell even if you move it to a different address. You do this in the top left corner, right next to the formula bar.

So in this case you could enter a name like "myCell" for the cell you want, then refer to it by writing "=myCell" as a formula in another cell.

Comment: You can't use a name like A1000 becuase its a valid cell reference